# How to delete many items in listbox?

Tags: c#, listbox

how to delete from listbox ?

deleting many indexes at the same time

Note that im using list of car types with their details
the objects in the listBox have  car type  cost  rate

Comment: Show us some code please..

Comment: Agreed, we can't help you without knowing what you've already tried.

Comment: try to google with your title

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: If you want to remove all selected items as commented:

```
foreach (int i in listBox1.SelectedIndices)
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
```

If you want to delete all items instead, use `Clear`:

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
```

if you want to remove at a specific index, use `RemoveAt`:

```
listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
```

or in a loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt();
```

if you want to remove a speicific item, use `Remove`:

```
Car car = (Car) listBox1.Items[0];
listBox1.Items.Remove(car);
```

Comment: im using this code  
                for (int x = listBox1.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; x >= 0; x--)
                {
                    int idx = listBox1.SelectedIndices[x];
                    listBox1.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[idx]);
                    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(idx);
                }

Answer (score 0):

You have to use loop.

Something like this:

```
List<int> indexesToDelete = new List<int>();

// add items you want to remove to List like this:
indexesToDelete.Add(1);
indexesToDelete.Add(2);
indexesToDelete.Add(4);

// loop will execute code inside inside for all items added to list
foreach (int indexToDelete in indexesToDelete)
{
    listbox1.RemoveAt(indexToDelete);
}
```

Edit: itemsToDelete renamed to indexesToDelete in code.

Comment: You have to use `Remove` when you want to use an object. Or you neeed to use a `for`-loop if you want to use the index with `RemoveAt`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter something is wrong with my code? My list is just list of indexes, not item objects. I used numbers (indexes).

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the code since you've named the variable itemsToDelete instead of indexToDelete. Note that you have not declared it and the loop syntax will also not compile.

Comment: You are right @TimSchmelter, i already fixed this. Too much PHP :)